# DebugCompileClasspath error when running code

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

so I´m trying to run my app and its giving this error

> ERROR: Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
> Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

I have tried doing some stuff that I saw here but still doesn´t work . Looking forward to hear from you :)

### Build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin:  'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'

android {
namespace 'com.example.project'
compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro
        }
    }
    
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
            apiVersion = '1.1'
            languageVersion = '1.1'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'
}
```

### Build.gradle(project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

plugins { id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false 
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false 
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false 
        id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.15" apply false 
        id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1'apply false }

 task clean(type: Delete) {delete rootProject.buildDir}
```